# systemd Vagrant and VirtualBox: wait for synced folder to mount

Tags: network-share, virtualbox, systemd, vagrant

I'm trying to setup a systemd service on a Vagrant box which requires the Vagrant synced folder to be mounted before starting.

**Vagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/yakkety64"
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/usr/local/src"
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap/bootstrap"
end
```

**/etc/systemd/system/my-server.service**

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /usr/local/src/index.js
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=my-server
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu

[Unit]
Requires=remote-fs.target
After=vboxguest.service
After=virtualbox-guest-utils.service

[Install]
WantedBy=remote-fs.target
```

If I do not enable the *my-server* service, the synced folder is properly mounted.  But when I attempt to enable the *my-server* service, the service fails to find the mounted files.  If I then login to the Vagrant box, the folder is not mounted.  It seems like the service's attempt to load files from that path interferes with Vagrant.

So, how do I wait for the folders to be mounted before my service starts?

Other solutions fall short in various ways, requiring manual intervention to start the service, which is unacceptable.

Answer (score 6):

I've just solved that kind of problem by adding:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target var-www-example.com.mount'
```

where `var-www-example.com` corresponds to:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/example.com"
```

in the `Vagrantfile`.

Thus, Vagrant has an XXX.mount systemd unit for each of its synced folder mount points. You can find yours with:

```
# systemctl list-units | fgrep .mount
```

Comment: I've tried some variations of this but it still doesn't seem to want to start after `vagrant.mount`. I don't suppose you've had to update this approach with newer box versions?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue where one of my systemd services required a vagrant synced filesystem be present prior to the service running to successfully start. I've worked around the problem by having a [vagrant shell provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html) restart the service automatically on every start. This works because the provisioner runs after vagrant has mounted the synced filesystems.

```
config.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: "systemctl restart my-server"
```

I'm not sure why your service would interfere with your synced filesystem. Vagrant syncs the folder that your vagrantfile is in by default to /vagrant. Could it have been mounted twice?