# systemctl start works, but systemctl enable fails with realpath() error

Tags: uwsgi, systemctl

I'm trying to set up a simple uwsgi service named `project` on Vagrant, Ubuntu 16.04.
It should start a simple Flask app that Nginx can talk to.

I can get the service to work when running
`systemctl start project`, but can't get service to run after boot with `systemctl enable project`.

Here is my `project.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /tmp/project.sock
uid = ubuntu
gid = ubuntu

chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

logto = /tmp/project.log
```

Here is my `/etc/systemd/system/project.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve project
After=network.target

[Service]
User=vagrant
Group=vagrant
WorkingDirectory=/home/vagrant/flask_trial
Environment="PATH=.:/home/vagrant/bin:/home/vagrant/.local/bin:/home/vagrant/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
ExecStart=/home/vagrant/anaconda3/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/vagrant/flask_trial/project.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Running `systemctl status project` after boot yields:

```
Sep 12 05:26:08 vagrant systemd[1]: Started uWSGI instance to serve project.
Sep 12 05:26:09 vagrant systemd[1]: project.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 12 05:26:09 vagrant systemd[1]: project.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 12 05:26:09 vagrant systemd[1]: project.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Running `journalctl | grep project` yields:

```
Sep 12 05:26:08 vagrant systemd[1]: Started uWSGI instance to serve project.
Sep 12 05:26:09 vagrant uwsgi[1123]: realpath() of /home/vagrant/flask_trial/project.ini failed: No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3618]
Sep 12 05:26:09 vagrant systemd[1]: project.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 12 05:26:09 vagrant systemd[1]: project.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 12 05:26:09 vagrant systemd[1]: project.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I suspect one of two problems: file permisions, since google shows people often struggle to get these right, or path, since realpath() fails.

Permission for `flask_trial` is

`drwxrwxr-x  1 vagrant vagrant       272 Sep 12 04:50 flask_trial`

For all files inside it:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 185 Sep 11 02:59 main.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 189 Sep 12 04:50 project.ini
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  70 Sep 11 03:47 wsgi.py
```

I enable service with `servicectl enable project`, without `sudo`, so that user should be `vagrant`.

Suspicious of path problem, as it looks like uwsgi can't findi project.ini, I tried modifying ExecStart to any of these:

```
ExecStart=/home/vagrant/anaconda3/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/vagrant/flask_trial/project.ini
ExecStart=/home/vagrant/anaconda3/bin/uwsgi --ini project.ini
ExecStart=/home/vagrant/anaconda3/bin/uwsgi --ini ./project.ini
```

None of above seems to work for boot, though all work for with `systemctl start`. Really lost here and would appreciate some comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, voicing your problems to others really helps you look at the issue at hand from a different angle.

There was nothing wrong with `systemctl` here. The problem was that my /flask_trial project was a shared Vagrant folder that apparently was linked with system AFTER `systemctl` run - so `systemctl` couldn't find `.ini` file. Silly me.

Once I knew what my problem is I knew what questions to ask and here's a nice solution:
https://serverfault.com/a/838390/435122